# How do I substitute network addresses?

Tags: command-line, networking

Right now I have a network server that I frequently have to SSH into. Instead of typing:

```
ssh fox@192.168.2.24
```

I want to be able to say:

```
ssh fox@srv
```

And that it would SSH into the server at 192.168.2.24.

Is this possible, and if yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Related: [Permanently store values when using the terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666788/permanently-store-values-when-using-the-terminal/)

Comment: In the same answer look for the  `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @steeldriver for pointing me at this (and correcting me).

To do this:

- Inside the .ssh folder in your home directory, create the file "config" if it doesn't exist.
- Add this to the file:

  ```
  Host srv
    Hostname 192.168.2.24
  ```

This will make it possible to type `ssh fox@srv` instead of the whole address. You can also add:

```
User fox
```

To just type `ssh srv`.

See the man page for `ssh_config` for full details.

Comment: Actually I would have recommended creating an entry for the server in your `~/.ssh/config` file instead

Comment: @steeldriver That sounds like it would work but I don't have that file. I do have a `known_hosts` file there though.

Comment: Aand after reading through your answer that seems like the much better option. Thanks!