# Shortcuts to SSH clients

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have many remote machines I need to log in. I need somehow store connection parameters because it is too boring enter them manually. Also I prefer to store password in these shortcuts. Software similar MTPuTTY that runs under windows would would solve my problem in Ubuntu.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Related: [Permanently store addresses when using SSH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666788/permanently-store-addresses-when-using-ssh). Use key-based authentication if possible.

Comment: Which command line parameters do you mean specifically? If it's just passwordless login you could use SSH keys, so a simple `ssh (user@)machinename` would be enough.

Comment: Another thing you might consider is that if it's actually just the 'boring' aspect, you can probably find it in your command history and just use a `!` command to execute it again.  try `history | grep ssh`

Answer (score 19):

You can do a lot using `.ssh/config` file. It would allow you to replace this:

```
ssh fooey@dev.example.com -p 22000
```

with:

```
ssh dev
```

to do so you have to add the following lines at the end of the `.ssh/config` (create it if does not exist)

```
Host dev
    HostName dev.example.com
    Port 22000
    User fooey
```

Concerning the storage of your credentials, I strongly advise you to use key authentification instead of password based.
You can create them either with a GUI or with your terminal.

**GUI**

open `Seahorse`, select `File > New`, then `Secure Shell Key` and let the interface guide you

**Terminal**
Create you RSA key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Store the Keys and Passphrase:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

Copy the Public Key

```
ssh-copy-id fooey@dev.example.com
```

Sources:

- http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to, you could make short shell scripts to launch your ssh sessions, then execute them either as s executable ( `chmod o+x`), or using the dot `.` command

Like make a file `~/ssh2hostA.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sshpass -p 'yourpassword' ssh user@hostA
```

then start it with

`. ~/ssh2hostA.sh`

Which is not a good thing to do because not only do you have passwords in cleartext scattered in your files, but people will probably be able to see the password in the `w` command. ( and `top`, and `/proc`)

Really, you should be using ssh host keys for this.

Really.

Comment: Strange, if I run souch file in command line like ./ttt it makes nothing - no messages and no ssh login

Comment: not sure how you made the file.   You probably can't just go `./filename` unless you set it's execution permission with `chmod`.  I suggested 'dotting' it.  `. filename` tells bash to read commands from a file.  Note the space between the dot and the filename.   Of course you can always go `sh -x filename` to gain some visibility about what it is doing when you run it