# Is there a way to change default ssh connect port?

Tags: ssh

I have a lot of servers that I changed my port to 2222.

Can I change on my computer the default port for ssh command? Instead of 22 I want to use 2222 as default.

For instance, instead of using `ssh root@ip -p 2222`

I want to use ssh root@ip only.

And when I need to use port 22 I type `ssh root@ip -p 22`

Comment: You can configure a port number per host in /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

Comment: . . . or per user via your `~/.ssh/config` file - similar to here [Permanently store addresses when using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666788/permanently-store-addresses-when-using-ssh/666798#666798)

Comment: ...or in your `~/.bashrc`: `alias ssh="ssh -p 2222 "`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your favorite editor to modify `~/.ssh/config`

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

and enter

```
Host *
User root
Port 2222
```

this would mean, by default, if you tried

```
ssh remote-host.com
```

SSH would actually do this

```
ssh -p 2222 root@remote-host.com
```

you can, of course, also specify this per host with a special username

```
Host remote-host1 remote-host2 remote-host3
User jackvanier
Port 2222
```

these settings can also co-exist

```
Host remote-host1 remote-host2 remote-host3
User jackvanier
Port 2222

Host *
User root
Port 2222
```

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61655/271588) for some more ideas.